# SolveValues function gives weird output

Tags: equation-solving

On Sep 21 edition of Notice of the AMS, it describes a few problems the mathematicians are working on, one of which reads:

> $x^3+y^3+z^3=n$ for which integer $0<n<100$; are there solutions with $x$,$y$,$z$ being integers?

The question is clear, short and not hard to understand. However, the progress of solving it might not finish yet. Therefore, I wonder if we could find some of the integers tuple $(x,y,z)$ for some $n$. For example, let $n$ be $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$, $8$, $9$ $10$, where we could employ the following Mathematica command to find solutions and print them in a table:

```
Table[{n, Solve[x^3 + y^3 + z^3 == n, {x, y, z}, Integers]}, {n, 1,10}]
```

However, the output of Mathematica look weird:
[image: Screenshot of Solve outputs]

Ok, let's use `NSolve` instead of `Solve`. Unfortunately, the same thing happens again:
[image: Screenshot of NSolve oputputs]

Given we just look for one solution of the equation, not all solutions, we probably could employ `SolveValues` instead of `Solve`. However, it doesn't change the output much:
[image: Screenshot of SolveValues outputs]

Then we tried `NSolveValues` instead of `SolveValues`. No improvements were observed:
[image]

Any ideas on why this happens and how to avoid it?

Comment: "wired" or "weird"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

"12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)"

sol = {Reduce[{x^3 + y^3 + z^3 == n, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0, 
     0 < n < 100}, {n, x, y, z}, Integers] // ToRules}

(* {{n -> 1, x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 1}, {n -> 1, x -> 0, y -> 1, 
  z -> 0}, {n -> 1, x -> 1, y -> 0, z -> 0}, {n -> 2, x -> 0, y -> 1, 
  z -> 1}, {n -> 2, x -> 1, y -> 0, z -> 1}, {n -> 2, x -> 1, y -> 1, 
  z -> 0}, {n -> 3, x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 1}, {n -> 8, x -> 0, y -> 0, 
  z -> 2}, {n -> 8, x -> 0, y -> 2, z -> 0}, {n -> 8, x -> 2, y -> 0, 
  z -> 0}, {n -> 9, x -> 0, y -> 1, z -> 2}, {n -> 9, x -> 0, y -> 2, 
  z -> 1}, {n -> 9, x -> 1, y -> 0, z -> 2}, {n -> 9, x -> 1, y -> 2, 
  z -> 0}, {n -> 9, x -> 2, y -> 0, z -> 1}, {n -> 9, x -> 2, y -> 1, 
  z -> 0}, {n -> 10, x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 2}, {n -> 10, x -> 1, 
  y -> 2, z -> 1}, {n -> 10, x -> 2, y -> 1, z -> 1}, {n -> 16, 
  x -> 0, y -> 2, z -> 2}, {n -> 16, x -> 2, y -> 0, 
  z -> 2}, {n -> 16, x -> 2, y -> 2, z -> 0}, {n -> 17, x -> 1, 
  y -> 2, z -> 2}, {n -> 17, x -> 2, y -> 1, z -> 2}, {n -> 17, 
  x -> 2, y -> 2, z -> 1}, {n -> 24, x -> 2, y -> 2, 
  z -> 2}, {n -> 27, x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 3}, {n -> 27, x -> 0, 
  y -> 3, z -> 0}, {n -> 27, x -> 3, y -> 0, z -> 0}, {n -> 28, 
  x -> 0, y -> 1, z -> 3}, {n -> 28, x -> 0, y -> 3, 
  z -> 1}, {n -> 28, x -> 1, y -> 0, z -> 3}, {n -> 28, x -> 1, 
  y -> 3, z -> 0}, {n -> 28, x -> 3, y -> 0, z -> 1}, {n -> 28, 
  x -> 3, y -> 1, z -> 0}, {n -> 29, x -> 1, y -> 1, 
  z -> 3}, {n -> 29, x -> 1, y -> 3, z -> 1}, {n -> 29, x -> 3, 
  y -> 1, z -> 1}, {n -> 35, x -> 0, y -> 2, z -> 3}, {n -> 35, 
  x -> 0, y -> 3, z -> 2}, {n -> 35, x -> 2, y -> 0, 
  z -> 3}, {n -> 35, x -> 2, y -> 3, z -> 0}, {n -> 35, x -> 3, 
  y -> 0, z -> 2}, {n -> 35, x -> 3, y -> 2, z -> 0}, {n -> 36, 
  x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}, {n -> 36, x -> 1, y -> 3, 
  z -> 2}, {n -> 36, x -> 2, y -> 1, z -> 3}, {n -> 36, x -> 2, 
  y -> 3, z -> 1}, {n -> 36, x -> 3, y -> 1, z -> 2}, {n -> 36, 
  x -> 3, y -> 2, z -> 1}, {n -> 43, x -> 2, y -> 2, 
  z -> 3}, {n -> 43, x -> 2, y -> 3, z -> 2}, {n -> 43, x -> 3, 
  y -> 2, z -> 2}, {n -> 54, x -> 0, y -> 3, z -> 3}, {n -> 54, 
  x -> 3, y -> 0, z -> 3}, {n -> 54, x -> 3, y -> 3, 
  z -> 0}, {n -> 55, x -> 1, y -> 3, z -> 3}, {n -> 55, x -> 3, 
  y -> 1, z -> 3}, {n -> 55, x -> 3, y -> 3, z -> 1}, {n -> 62, 
  x -> 2, y -> 3, z -> 3}, {n -> 62, x -> 3, y -> 2, 
  z -> 3}, {n -> 62, x -> 3, y -> 3, z -> 2}, {n -> 64, x -> 0, 
  y -> 0, z -> 4}, {n -> 64, x -> 0, y -> 4, z -> 0}, {n -> 64, 
  x -> 4, y -> 0, z -> 0}, {n -> 65, x -> 0, y -> 1, 
  z -> 4}, {n -> 65, x -> 0, y -> 4, z -> 1}, {n -> 65, x -> 1, 
  y -> 0, z -> 4}, {n -> 65, x -> 1, y -> 4, z -> 0}, {n -> 65, 
  x -> 4, y -> 0, z -> 1}, {n -> 65, x -> 4, y -> 1, 
  z -> 0}, {n -> 66, x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 4}, {n -> 66, x -> 1, 
  y -> 4, z -> 1}, {n -> 66, x -> 4, y -> 1, z -> 1}, {n -> 72, 
  x -> 0, y -> 2, z -> 4}, {n -> 72, x -> 0, y -> 4, 
  z -> 2}, {n -> 72, x -> 2, y -> 0, z -> 4}, {n -> 72, x -> 2, 
  y -> 4, z -> 0}, {n -> 72, x -> 4, y -> 0, z -> 2}, {n -> 72, 
  x -> 4, y -> 2, z -> 0}, {n -> 73, x -> 1, y -> 2, 
  z -> 4}, {n -> 73, x -> 1, y -> 4, z -> 2}, {n -> 73, x -> 2, 
  y -> 1, z -> 4}, {n -> 73, x -> 2, y -> 4, z -> 1}, {n -> 73, 
  x -> 4, y -> 1, z -> 2}, {n -> 73, x -> 4, y -> 2, 
  z -> 1}, {n -> 80, x -> 2, y -> 2, z -> 4}, {n -> 80, x -> 2, 
  y -> 4, z -> 2}, {n -> 80, x -> 4, y -> 2, z -> 2}, {n -> 81, 
  x -> 3, y -> 3, z -> 3}, {n -> 91, x -> 0, y -> 3, 
  z -> 4}, {n -> 91, x -> 0, y -> 4, z -> 3}, {n -> 91, x -> 3, 
  y -> 0, z -> 4}, {n -> 91, x -> 3, y -> 4, z -> 0}, {n -> 91, 
  x -> 4, y -> 0, z -> 3}, {n -> 91, x -> 4, y -> 3, 
  z -> 0}, {n -> 92, x -> 1, y -> 3, z -> 4}, {n -> 92, x -> 1, 
  y -> 4, z -> 3}, {n -> 92, x -> 3, y -> 1, z -> 4}, {n -> 92, 
  x -> 3, y -> 4, z -> 1}, {n -> 92, x -> 4, y -> 1, 
  z -> 3}, {n -> 92, x -> 4, y -> 3, z -> 1}, {n -> 99, x -> 2, 
  y -> 3, z -> 4}, {n -> 99, x -> 2, y -> 4, z -> 3}, {n -> 99, 
  x -> 3, y -> 2, z -> 4}, {n -> 99, x -> 3, y -> 4, 
  z -> 2}, {n -> 99, x -> 4, y -> 2, z -> 3}, {n -> 99, x -> 4, 
  y -> 3, z -> 2}} *)

And @@ (And @@ {x^3 + y^3 + z^3 == n, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0, 
     0 < n < 100} /. sol)

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** Including negative integers. Also, to eliminate the unnecessary permutations, **assume that `{x, y, z}` are ordered**.

```
sol2 = Solve[{x^3 + y^3 + z^3 == n, 0 < n < 100, x >= y >= z}, 
  {n, x, y, z}, Integers]
```

[image]

To avoid the [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) functions, the variables need to be bounded.

```
sol3 = Solve[{x^3 + y^3 + z^3 == n, 0 < n < 100, 
    x >= y >= z, -200 < x < 200, -200 < y < 200, -200 < z < 200}, 
    {n, x, y, z}, Integers] // Short[#, 20] &
```

[image]

Comment: Since the problem says integers and not nonnegative integers, this misses solutions for n=6 and n=7 and others.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use FindInstance in these case:

```
Table[{n, 
  FindInstance[x^3 + y^3 + z^3 == n && 0 < n < 100, {x, y, z}, 
   Integers]}, {n, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, `FindInstance` still leaves some $n$s unsolved, for example, when $n==4$.

Comment: @TJM Why do you believe there are solutions for n=4?

Comment: @CarlWoll I can't say there must be a solution for $n=4$. However, there's also no proof for the solution doesn't exist when $n=4$.